# Can you simplify this if-statement?

Tags: java, simplify

I am looking to somehow simplify the following: `monthNbr==11||monthNbr==4||monthNbr==6||monthNbr==9` here:

```
public int daysPerMonth (int monthNbr){
    if(monthNbr==11||monthNbr==4||monthNbr==6||monthNbr==9){
        return 30;
    } else if (monthNbr==2) {
        return 28;
    } else {
        return 31;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

perhaps it would look nicer with the new switch expressions

```
public int daysPerMonth(int monthNbr) {
    return switch (monthNbr) {
        case 11, 4, 6, 9 -> 30;
        case 2 -> 28;
        default -> 31;
    };
}
```

Comment: This, however, would only work since [`Java 12`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html).

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel:

```
Month.of(monthNbr).length(isLeapYear)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, you can also do:

```java
public int daysPerMonth(int monthNbr) {
    return YearMonth.of(Year.now().getValue(),monthNbr).lengthOfMonth();
}
```

and this will get you the number of the months for the current year.

Also, note, that `Switch Expressions` can be only used since Java 12.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one smaller version, it should also be easy to extend to support leap years. Either by send the year or send year 2000 if you want leap year.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.time.*;

public class HelloDays
{
     public static int daysPerMonth(int monthNbr)
     {
        YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(1999, monthNbr);
        return yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth();  
     }
     
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        System.out.println(daysPerMonth(1));  // 31
        System.out.println(daysPerMonth(2));  // 28
        System.out.println(daysPerMonth(4));  // 30
        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream like this.

```
public int daysPerMonth(int monthNbr) {
    if (IntStream.of(11, 4, 6, 9).anyMatch(i -> monthNbr == i)) {
        return 30;
    } else if (monthNbr == 2) {
        return 28;
    } else {
        return 31;
    }
}
```